# Puppet file_line only if file exists

Tags: puppet

I've got a file_line that I'd like to execute on any system where a given file exists, but be ignored on all where the file doesn't.

```
file_line {'java_security_random':
  line  => 'securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom',
  path  => '/etc/alternatives/jre/lib/security/java.security',
  match => /^securerandom.source=.*/,
}
```

The problem with this is that I get errors on all hosts where java isn't installed. We don't use Puppet to manage or install java, so I'm not sure how to put in a manifest-based dependency for this. What's the most Puppet-esque way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably<sup>1</sup> need to create a custom fact that reports on the existence of this file.

```ruby
# has_java_security.rb

Facter.add(:has_java_security) do
  setcode do
    File.exist?('/etc/alternatives/jre/lib/security/java.security')
  end
end
```

And in your manifest:

```puppet
if $facts['has_java_security'] {
  file_line {'java_security_random':
    line  => 'securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom',
    path  => '/etc/alternatives/jre/lib/security/java.security',
    match => /^securerandom.source=.*/,
  }
}
```

For more on how to write custom facts see [here](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.9/custom_facts.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> I am assuming, of course, that you have a good reason for using one tool to manage Java and Puppet to manage the line in this file.

Comment: We do, yes. It's all part of the conversion process as we bring things which have been managed by hand (or through RPM dependencies) under Puppet management. But you're bang on and I can't believe I didn't think to build a fact. I've done that in a dozen other places.